# How to split a unicode string by a specified delimiter in php?

Tags: php, unicode, split

Sorry if the question sounds noob. My problem is I have an text file and need to import the data to database.

The reading process is fine, when I `print_r` the line it's correct.

Then I need to split it by the tab(\t)  delimiter. Then all the unicode characters are broken.

Here's how I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Test page for project XY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Test Page</h1>
     <pre>
     <?php
include 'ChromePhp.php';
ChromePhp::log('Start read file!');
ini_set("default_charset", 'utf-8');
$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        print_r($line); // if print the $line here, it's fine
        $myArray = preg_split("/[\t]/", $line); //=> broken unicode, adding u not work
        $myArray = explode("\t", $line);//=> same
        print_r($myArray);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
    // ChromePhp::log('Cant open file!');
    print_r ('Cant open file!');
} 
?>


     </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update: I tried this as suggestions, but still not work :(

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8"); 
$tab="\t";
$myArray=(mb_split($tab,$line));
print_r($myArray);`
```

Comment: You probably only need the unicode modifier: `preg_split("/[\t]/u", $line)`

Comment: Hi, I tried `preg_split("/[\t]/u", $line)` but characters like  �� still appears :(

Comment: Is your php source file also utf-8?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, it was UTF-8 with no BOM. I tried switch to UTF-8 but nothing changed :(

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: You should try using mb_split, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php

Comment: I tried, not work. Please scroll to the end of the question, I updated it.

Comment: What's your string?

Comment: Thank all you guys for the attention. It turns out my bad that the input.txt is encoded in UCS-2 :p

Answer (score 0):

Try run it in terminal, i think you have error in view. Try to put header instruction in php and say it codepage = UTF-8. Also you need to check the php file codepage itself.

Comment: Thank you for the attention. It turns out my bad that the input.txt is encoded in UCS-2 :p